# How can I parse in this scenario using python regexp?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Sorry for the bad title, but I can't find specific word to describe this question.

**My test string:**

> MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=["u don't
>   know anything about it"], type_arguments=["u don't know anything about
>   it"],
>   target=....................................................................
>   ......................................................................MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed',
>   arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], type_arguments=["u don't
>   know anything about it"], target='super',

"u don't know anything about it" means this part is unknown, you must use .* or .*? to parse it.

**My wish result: the second MethodInvocation can be paresed.**

> MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=["u don't
>   know anything about it"], type_arguments=["u don't know anything about
>   it"], target='super',

**My fail regexp:**

> MethodInvocation\(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=\[.*?\],
>   type_arguments=\[.*?\], target='super'

This regexp will parse all of the result instead of the second MethodInvocation.

How can I parse it using python regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leo, give this regexp a try:

```
MethodInvocation\(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=\[[^\]]*\], type_arguments=\[[^\]]*\], target='super',
```

Which returns only:

"MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], type_arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], target='super',"

It works by ensuring that your unknown argument groups (u don't know...) terminate at the first ending bracket by excluding that character from those parts of the search.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your ^\] is not fit my question "u don't know anything about it" (because this regexp might miss in this following situation: `MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=["abcd]abcd"], type_arguments=["abcd]abcd"], target='super',`, however, my goal is parse all super method invocation in Java, it is impossible to leave "]" in the argument, so maybe your answer will be good for me. I just wander if there are better answer or not.

Comment: Leo, you are correct, I wrote this under the assumption that "]" would not be in there. Unfortunately, if "u don't know" could literally contain "anything", then no regexp exists that would correctly parse the string all the time because you could even have things like "], target='super'" in there. I figured the absence of "]" was a safe assumption, but I'll be interested to see if someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `finditer()`?

```
import re

s="""MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], type_arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], target=.................................................................... ......................................................................MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], type_arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], target='super',"""

ind=[]
for a in re.finditer('MethodInvocation', s):
    ind.append((a.start(), a.end()))

#ind[1][0] - starting index of the second string
output = s[ind[1][0]:len(s)]
print(output)
```

And the output is:

```
MethodInvocation(name='isOnlySingleDcAllowed', arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], type_arguments=["u don't know anything about it"], target='super',
```